# How can I keep my req.user constant in all views?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS and Express:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.CurrentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

app.get('/pics/:id', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    User.find({"_id": req.params.id}, function(err, userProfile) { 
        if(err) {
            console.log("error on profile page: " + err)
        } else {
            res.render("user-profile", {userProfile: userProfile});
        }
    })
})
```

Here's my shortened server code. Now on the client-side I'm trying to use my res.locals code, and I'm finding that the username attribute stays constant but not the ID.

```
<%=CurrentUser.username%>
<%=CurrentUser._id%>
```

The above code produces:
Sean 5aea9a9d66c1a878787594f1 
when I query http://localhost:3000/pics/5aeaafe552984a856080644b

And it produces: 
Sean 5aeaafe552984a856080644b
when I query http://localhost:3000/pics/5aeaafe552984a856080644b

How can I keep the ._id attribute of CurrentUser constant like the name?

Comment: When you use a local strategy with passport, you need to use the function `req.logIn` when you have found your user in the database. After, it will be persistent in `req.user`

Comment: I'm also using passport.authenticate. 

According to the docs: "Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which req.login() can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user."

[here is my login route]        
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        successRedirect: "/home",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res) {
})

Comment: I see on a post from stackoverflow that if you use a local strategy. It become your responsability to invoke req.logIn. I've had the same problem as you. Try to `req.logIn(userProfile, function(err))` just after the `find` method